Unable to pan a nested ReactFlow editor
I am trying to nest a ReactFlow (RF) pane within a node of a parent RF container. So far, I am able to control the inner RF as an independent editor - I can zoom, drag its nodes, and form edges. One thing I cannot seem to resolve is panning the inner RF pane with the default mouse click and drag. I have tried recommended solutions such as stopping the parent's event propagation to switching the panning control scheme (i.e. Space+drag to pan), to no avail.
Is there something I am missing?
My codesandbox for a minimally reproducible example.
